# jQuery show only one div at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a jQuery plugin to show/hide divs but I'm not sure how to get it to only show one div at a time, so when I click the link to show a div, it hides all the other ones currently open and shows only the most recent one clicked.

Here is the jQuery:

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.showHide = function (options) {

    //default vars for the plugin
    var defaults = {
        speed: 1000,
        easing: '',
        changeText: 0,
        showText: 'Show',
        hideText: 'Hide'

    };
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    $(this).click(function () { 
         $('.toggleDiv').slideUp(options.speed, options.easing);    
         // this var stores which button you've clicked
         var toggleClick = $(this);
         // this reads the rel attribute of the button to determine which div id to toggle
         var toggleDiv = $(this).attr('rel');
         // here we toggle show/hide the correct div at the right speed and using which easing effect
         $(toggleDiv).slideToggle(options.speed, options.easing, function() {
         // this only fires once the animation is completed
         if(options.changeText==1){
         $(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.text(options.hideText) : toggleClick.text(options.showText);
         }
          });

      return false;

    });

};
})(jQuery);
```

And this is the class you add to a link to make a div show/hide:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.show_hide').showHide({           
    speed: 1000,  // speed you want the toggle to happen    
    easing: '',  // the animation effect you want. Remove this line if you dont want an effect and if you haven't included jQuery UI
    changeText: 0, // if you dont want the button text to change, set this to 0
    showText: 'View',// the button text to show when a div is closed
    hideText: 'Close' // the button text to show when a div is open
}); 
});
```

Which would be used with:

```
<a class="show_hide" href="#" rel="#slidingDiv">View</a></pre>
<div id="slidingDiv" class="toggleDiv" style="display: none;">Content</div>
```

Anyone got any ideas how to make it to only allow you to open one at a time? As currently it is allowing multiple divs to be open at the same time!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are the *multiple divs*, show you full html. You might have elements with same ID

Comment: Your code is works good and show only one div at time: http://jsfiddle.net/dwcbkzaw/. What the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There's this thing called jQuery UI Accordion. With a call of a function, jQuery will automatically transform your list of `div`s into an accordion. An accordion is a show/hide mechanism that only shows one `div` at a time.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <div id="accordion">
    <h3>Div #1</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <h3>Div #2</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <h3>Div #3</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <h3>Div #4</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <h3>Div #5</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
    </div>
<script>
$("#accordion").accordion();
</script>
```